# Creating an XML-based help system in Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I'm creating an application with a help system based on XML. I need to
know how to populate TreeView and ListView controls with XML data
(specification below).

- TreeView: `<root>` and `<topic>` tags.
- ListView: `<document>` tag (with group and icon dependent on if it's a
  web link or local file link, but I can do it).

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

XML can be used via ADO.NET or LINQ like any other data source, so using LINQ you can populate a Tree-View.

Here is an excellent HOW-TO article on how to do it:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210616114234/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/043008-1.aspx

Comment: That is for APS.NET, WinForms is different.

Comment: Thomas, look for XmlDataDocument.

Comment: Did you actually look at tags? I was looking for something for winforms, not webpages...